# Convert Object to String

Tags: java, string, object, get, converters

I have a couple to class in which I'm getting and setting a few things and then finally calling it in my main method. But when I call my class in the main method it just gives me the object instead of name,address and age. I know this structure is very complicated but I want to keep this structure because later on I will be adding a lot of things to this. It would be AMAZING if someone could tell me how to do this. I would really appreciate this. Below is my code for all my classes

This is my first class

```
   public class methodOne
    {
      public String getName()
      {
         String name = "UserOne";
         return name;
      }

     public int getAge()
     {
        int age = 17;
        return age;
     }

     public String getAddress()
     {
       String address  = "United States";
       return address;
     }
 }
```

This is my second class

```
    public class methodTwo
{
   String name;
   String address;
   int age;

   public methodTwo(methodOne objectOne)
   {
     name=objectOne.getName();
     address=objectOne.getAddress();
     age=objectOne.getAge();
   }
   public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

This is my third class

```
public class methodThree {

        private methodTwo methodTwoInMethodThree;
        private methodOne methodOneInMethodThree;

        public methodThree()
        {
            this.methodOneInMethodThree = new methodOne();
            this.methodTwoInMethodThree = new methodTwo(methodOneInMethodThree);
        }

        public methodTwo getMethodTwoInMethodThree() {
            return methodTwoInMethodThree;
        }

        public void setMethodTwoInMethodThree(methodTwo methodTwoInMethodThree) {
            this.methodTwoInMethodThree = methodTwoInMethodThree;
        }


}
```

This is my fourth class which is the method maker

```
public class methodMaker {

    public methodThree brandNewFunction(methodTwo object)
    {
        methodThree thirdMethod = new  methodThree();

        thirdMethod.setMethodTwoInMethodThree(object);

        return thirdMethod;
    }

}
```

This is my main class which calls methodMaker. What I want to achieve is that when I print the value it should print the name,address and age but instead it just prints trial.methodThree@4de5ed7b

```
public class mainClass {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    methodMaker makerOfMethods  = new methodMaker();
    methodOne one = new methodOne();
    methodTwo object = new methodTwo(one);

    System.out.println(makerOfMethods.brandNewFunction(object).toString());

}
```

}

Comment: override toString() method in your methodTwo class.

Comment: Implement the `toString()` method!

Comment: I like Innovation's option, but you could serialise to xml and fetch the node/attribute you need.

Comment: I was also thinking about toString() method. But where exactly should I implement it? and how?

Comment: you need to override the toString() method as Innovation said and also try follow the naming conventions for methods, classes which is good for readability purpose.

Comment: where should I override it??

Comment: In whatever class you want to print. Why do you have `MethodOne` and `MethodTwo` classes? `MethodOne` is not needed IMO.

Comment: I want to print in the main method but when I do System.out.println(makerOfMethods.brandNewFunction(object).toString()) it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to override the default implementation of the [`.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method in the objects you want to print out:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Name: " + this.name; 
}
```

EDIT:
I do not know exactly where you are printing, and you naming convention doesn't really help out, but from what I am understanding, you would need to implement it in all of you classes since they all seem to be related to each other.

So, in your `methodOne` class (can also be applied to `methodTwo`):

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Name: " + this.name + " Age: " + this.age + " Address: + " this.address;
}
```

In your `methodThree` class:

```
 private methodTwo methodTwoInMethodThree;
 private methodOne methodOneInMethodThree;

@Override
public String toString()
{
    StringBulder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(this.methodTwoInMethodThree != null)
    {
         sb.append("Method 2:").append(methodTwoInMethodThree.toString());
    }

    if(methodOneInMethodThree != null)
    {
        sb.append("Method 1:").append(methodOneInMethodThree.toString());
    }  

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: in which method should I implement this?

Comment: This is a method which has already defined on Object by fathers of java. Just override it.

Comment: in method two? or three?

Comment: In the methodThree what should I return from the toString() method?

Comment: @user3690321: you need to return `sb.toString()`. I just noticed now that I left it out, should be fixed now.

Comment: Method 2:trial.methodTwo@3590ed52Method 1:Name: UserOne Age: 17 Address:  United States, can't I only have it as Method 1:Name: UserOne Age: 17 Address:  United States? Or is this not possible. But thanks very very much all this help. You're the best

Comment: @user3690321: In my answer next to the `toString()` method for `methodOne` I also made a small point the same can be done for `mehtod2`. I did not write it explicitely so that I can keep my answer concise.

Comment: I actually just have one last question. If I not set any other variable like birthplace but I don't add that to the toString method. It won't get printed correct?

Comment: @user3690321: Yes correct. If it will not be in the `toString()` method it will not be shown, you would need to add it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
System.out.println(myObject);
```

Implicitly , java calls instead

```
System.out.println(myObject.toString());
```

So, if in `MyClass`, you override `toString()`, then whatever your `toString` method returns is what's gonna be printed.

---

Side note: are you confusing classes and methods? Methods are functions in your classes, classes are wrappers around a bunch of attributes and methods. Your naming is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
 public class methodTwo
{
   String name;
   String address;
   int age;

   public methodTwo(methodOne objectOne)
   {
     name=objectOne.getName();
     address=objectOne.getAddress();
     age=objectOne.getAge();
   }
   public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String toString(){
      return name+" "+address+" "+age;
    }

}
```

Comment: @user3690321 where you print methodTwo. I can't see it in your code!

Comment: I don't print methodTwo. I print methodMaker, this is in the main class

Comment: Then add the method toString to methodMaker and there you call methodTo.toString()

Comment: I can't add it in the method maker because I don't have the name, address and age parameters!

Comment: Add `public String toString(){
      return thirdMethod.getMethodTwoInMethodThree().toString     }
`

Answer (score 0):

Are you printing the object using println()?

From the docs, println():

> calls at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value

This string value is obtained from the object's toString() method, which:

> returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object

So if you want to print anything other than this you have to override the toString() method in your object and return a string containing whatever you want.

Just google "override tostring java" and you will see a ton of examples.